# HOW TO: Layout images in a view that mimics the layout of application icons on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

The iPhone shows applications icons, with the application name below ea. icon, on the screen 4 across and 4 down.

What is the best way to replicate this type of view in a custom iPhone application?

For example, I'd like to show a grid of players in a game I'm developing in a UIScrollView that shows a thumbnail of each player and their name.  I'd like to show a maximum of 4 such "cells" per row and just keep on generating rows as needed based on player count (e.g. given 10 players I'd have 3 rows ... the first two would have 4 player thumbs and the last would have 2).

Is there a custom UIViewController for something like this perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. You could do it with a `UIScrollView` directly, but the table view implements some cell-reusing behavior that you'll probably want to utilize.

Depending on whether the performance on the device is acceptable you could either create a custom `UIView` subclass to draw the icon and label (cleaner), or draw them directly to the cell's view using the drawing primitives (faster).

Comment: What is strange to me is that the UITableViewCell represents an entire row ... not really "just" a cell per se.  I'm trying to create a table with 4 cells per row, each representing an player and providing the behavior to be selected/un-selected, etc...